# How to add/use an AJAX control in a non-AJAX enabled website in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, autocomplete

I have started a simple website using ASP.NET but it is not an AJAX-enabled project. Now what I need is to use an AJAX control (specifically Autocomplete) but I do not know how to add it to my website. What I should do guys? Do I need to add something in my library?

What should I do in order to see it in the toolbox..?

Please help me I'm just a newbie...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Which autocomplete?  JQuery's or ASP.Net's?

Comment: ASP.NET`s autocomplete sir...

Answer (score 0):

Well unless you use ajaxcontroltoolkit, you cant use asp.net ajax autocomplete. I suggest you use some other javascript library and use its autocomplete feature. jQuery and Mootoold (my fav) both have autocomplete plugins

Comment: thats it... I want to use ajaxcontroltoolkit... but since my web project is not AJAX-enabled, I dont see the autocomplete control or any ajax controls in the toolbox... please teach me sir...

Comment: http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx

Comment: my question: Is it possible to use ASP.NET Autocomplete (from AJAX control toolkit) when your project was started as a non AJAX-enabled project?